# Initialize a project with JPA and Hibernate, get an error: "Unable to locate persister"

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I'm trying to create a project including JavaFX, Hibernate and JPA. I don't know what went wrong with the configuration.

Here is my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">password</property>

        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.example.demo.Resident"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
             xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd"
             version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <class>com.example.demo.Resident</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_schema"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value="giao256.getMySQL"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My module-info.java

```
module com.example.demo {
    requires jakarta.persistence;
    requires lombok;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires java.naming;


    opens com.example.demo to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.demo;
}
```

Resident is a typical entity class with @Entity, @Id, etc. annotations.

For the first time I meet the "Unable to locate persister" error, I find myself didn't include entity class to configuration files. But now I don't know what else to do.

Thanks for your time.

Update: Here is my stacktrace

```java
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:364)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1135)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:196)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate persister: com.example.demo.Resident
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.4.Final/org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:758)
    at org.hibernate.orm.core@6.2.4.Final/org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:739)
    at com.example.demo/com.example.demo.DemoApplication.start(DemoApplication.java:25)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@21/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.example.demo.DemoApplication
```

Comment: For starters move the properties from `hibernate.cfg.xml` to the `persistence.xml`. Please include the stacktrace you get, as that contains essential information.

Comment: Do you use SessionFactory? Because probably is required.  See this https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2490801

Comment: At first I wanted to include the stack trace too but Stack Overflow considered my post as spam so I removed it because I guessed it might not be as important as others.

Comment: I removed JPA configurations from my project, and also add to module-info.java `opens ... to org.hibernate.orm.core`. and somehow it worked. I don't know the reason why. While searching for a solution, I went to Hibernate official site and try this tutorial [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/quickstart/html_single/#tutorial_annotations) but couldn't even make it run properly.